# Radians missing from NSolve result

Tags: equation-solving, units

Why does the result not include radians in the solution for `a`? This does not occur if I use meters instead of radians.

```
NSolve[{Quantity[11.2, ("Radians")/("Seconds")] == a t, 
  t == Quantity[2.92, "Seconds"], d == .5 a t^2}, {a, t, d}]
```

Result:

```
{{t -> Quantity[2.92, "Seconds"], 
  a -> Quantity[3.83562, 1/("Seconds")^2], d -> 16.352}}
```

Comment: Simpler example: `Solve[w == Quantity[11.2, ("Radians")/("Seconds")], w]`.  Of course one definition of radian measure is (arc length)/(radius), which is dimensionless.

Comment: I see. What if I have a system of equations with radians and revolutions? Will Mathematica distinguish and convert between the two?

Comment: It seems to: `Solve[w == Quantity[11.2, ("Revolutions")/("Seconds")], w]`. I only suggested it because I don't know for sure how *Mathematica* treats `"Radians"`.  But it looks like `Solve` converts revolutions to (unitless) radians.

Comment: It looks like `"Revolutions"` is automatically multiplied by `2\[Pi]`

Comment: Yes, just so.  It seems to happen automatically in `Solve` or `NSolve`. I don't know what you can do, if you do not want that to happen.

Comment: Now that I know that radians are unitless and how revolutions are handled, everything is fine.

Answer (score 4):

[Radians](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radian#Definition) are a [dimensionless quantity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimensionless_quantity)